# Crawling and finding keywords for images without any "alt" attribute

Tags: python, image, web-crawler

I am writing an image crawler that scrapes the images from a Web page. This done by finding the img tag on the Web page. But recently I noticed, some img tags don't have an alt attribute in it. Is there any way to find the keywords for that particular image?

And are there any precautions for crawling the websites for images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no alt attribute in a tag, or it is empty, check fo attribute name, if not name, check for id. Well, id, when .asp or .aspx for instance, doesn't have to make sense. But, well, as a last resort, use src attribute by getting just the filename without an extension. Sometimes attribute class can also be used, but, well, I don't recomend it. Even id can be very much deceiving.

You will have trouble with JS imposed images, of course, but even that can be solved with a lot of time and will.

As for precautions, what  exactly do you mean? Check whether src is really an image or what?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, I meant to ask for that JS imposed images problem which you pointed out. Any pointers on that?

Comment: For that you will have to parse JS from inside a &lt;script&gt;&lt;/script&gt; or download a JS file from src specified in script tag. To find out any image imposed dynamically, you will have to implement code that recognizes any action around Image() object. See JS docs for that. Also, many people use JQuery, so better to be ready for its interface as well.

Comment: For more robust  solution, there is nothing to be done but to have JS interpreter which will return you complete src, or alt or whatever. Python can use external interpreters of JS as Firefox or OS builtins through some libraries. But first look around how Google and other crawlers do this.

Comment: Thanks again. Will look for it.